# How to train image for image recognition during runtime with neuroph studio?

Tags: java, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am using this code to use the existing TRAINING PARAMETERS to do an image recognition test with the help of neuroph studio. Using neuroph studio I had
to train images first as described here http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/image_recognition.html

```
    NeuralNetwork nnet = NeuralNetwork.load("MyImageRecognition.nnet"); 
    ImageRecognitionPlugin imageRecognition    =(ImageRecognitionPlugin)nnet.getPlugin(ImageRecognitionPlugin.class); 
    HashMap<String, Double> output = imageRecognition.recognizeImage(new File("someImage.jpg"));
    System.out.println(output.toString());
```

So What I want to do is train the image during runtime of my java application and add to the previous parameters if it exists. So is it possible to do it, if yes then how? I am absolutely clueless. Thank you in advance.